# Can I perform autocorrelation / lag analysis on a zoo object in R with non-regular time steps? If so, how?

Tags: r, correlation, lag, zoo

Can I perform autocorrelation / lag analysis on a zoo object in R with non-regular time steps? If so, how?

The only other post I could find here dealt with regular time series. I have a sequence of observations taken at irregular time steps.  For example, `(t,y) = (0,2668), (36.62,2723), (42,2723),...` where

- `t` is the time in hours, and
- `y` is the (categorical*) observation. ... *edited from original post

I would like to look for lag correlations daily (lag = 24) and weekly (lag = 168) to see whether certain categories of observation repeat at / near these lag intervals.  Is there a way to do this in R?  I created a zoo object for my data but have been unable to find any documentation concerning how to do this.

Comment: I don't know much about `zoo` objects, but there is a method in the `nlme` package (`corCAR1`) for incorporating first-order autoregression in a model with unevenly spaced data (using `g[n]ls` or `[n]lme`).

Comment: Thanks!  This looks like a great package that I can use on some other data I have to analyze.  I didn't realize until after my initial post that I was being silly ... my observations are categorical.  Nevertheless, while I don't think I can use this package on this data, I think I can use it later.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `aggregate` to convert your data into daily & weekly intervals, and then calculate the autocorrelation with whatever function does it for regular time series (say `acf`). e.g.:

```
# make a data set to play with
library(zoo)
ts <- sort(runif(100)*168*3) # 100 observations over 3 weeks
ys <- runif(100)       # y values
z <- zoo(ys, order.by=ts)

# ** convert to daily/weekly. ?aggregate.zoo
# NOTE: can use ts instead of index(z)
z.daily <- aggregate(z,index(z) %/% 24)    # has 21 elements (one per day)
z.weekly <- aggregate(z,index(z) %/% 168)  # has 3 elements (one per week)

# Now compute correlation, lag 1 (index in z.daily/weekly)
daily.acf <- acf(z.daily, lag.max=1)[1]
weekly.acf <- acf(z.weekly, lag.max=1)[1]
```

The `aggregate` converts `z` to daily or weekly data where you sum all occurences for each day/week. It does the grouping by looking at `index(z) %/% 24` (or 168) which is the integer part of the hour of observation divided by 24 (ie, the day it occurs).

Then the `acf`  function calculates autocorrelation (with the `lag` being on indices of the vector, not on time).

I don't really know much about statistics, and one thing I noticed was that if you do:

```
weekly.acf <- acf(z.daily,lag.max=7)[7]
```

you get a different answer from when you calculate autocorrelation from `z.weekly`, because it's doing autocorrelation on *daily* data with a lag of 7 as opposed to weekly data with a lag of 1 -- so I'm not sure if what I'm doing is actualy what you want.

Comment: Hi. Thank you for your help.  I played around with this and then realized I was being silly because my y observations are categorical, not continuous.  Thus, I can't sum the observations to get meaningful data.  I was hoping to find if any categories repeat at / near certain lags but this may be difficult since I don't have data measurements at those regularly-spaced time intervals. If I am working with continuous data in the future, I will remember this aggregate though.  Thanks for your help!